# How to persist/save Objects in XML Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

I want to save Object values in xml file which is located in my Spring MVC project's SRC folder.

I little bit know about  marshaling and un-marshaling concept of JAX-B for saving object to xml file.

```
example ,
    Employee emp1=new Employee(1,"Robin",50000);  
    File file =new File("c://myfiles//employee.xml"))  
    marshallerObj.marshal(emp1, new FileOutputStream(file);
```

here above code save the my emplyee object to employee.xml file which is locate in C/myfiles folder.

so how i can use same code in spring controller 
like below,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveNotice",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveNotice(Notice notice){

    Employee emp1=new Employee(1,"Robin",50000);  
    File file =new File("src/employee.xml"))  
    marshallerObj.marshal(emp1, new FileOutputStream(file); 
}
```

need help here........

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

buddy .

1 assume that
  your src folder is   c://workspace//myproject//src//
  your class output folder is c://workspace//myproject//WEB-ROOT//

2 when your class is invoked by tomcat ,tomcat will make "src/emplyee.xml" as a relative path ,and translate  it to "c://workspace//myproject//WEB-ROOT//src//emplyee.xml"  finally .
so ,the filenotfoundexception will be throwed.

3 if you really want read emplyee.xml which is in   c://workspace//myproject//src// 

you can use  absolute path :

File file =new File("c://workspace//myproject//src//employee.xml"))

or you can move your employee.xml to  "c://workspace//myproject//WEB-ROOT//src//emplyee.xml"

Comment: ,i cannot pass full path directly to File constructor becoz at localhost i am working in Windows OS and my live server is on Linux OS.So in that case employee.xml file path changes.I want relative path.

Comment: have a try :  File file =new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/").getPath()+"employee.xml")

Answer (score 0):

To marshall an object and then save its state in a file situated within of the classpath you have to do the following step:

1. Annote your model's object

   ```
   @XmlRootElement
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   public class Employee {

   @XmlAttribute (required = true)
   private String id;
   @XmlAttribute (required = true)
   private String name;
   @XmlAttribute (required = true)
   private String salary;

   //Getter and setter method

   }
   ```
2. Marshall your object

   ```
   JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
   Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
   m.marshal(creditCard, new File("/employee.xml"));
   ```